# Setting a value to a variable in an equation

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.fit()` is giving me a polynomial equation.
Now I want to put different values of x into the equation to get corresponding y values.
How to do that? I cannot put different x-values to the polynomial equation even though I have set it as a variable.

If I set x=10 and y=poly_fitting it doesn't work.

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as poly
poly_fitting= poly.fit(x_trimmed, y_trimmed, 10)
print("poly_fitting=", poly_fitting)
```

Result:

```
poly_fitting= 0.0008463953270006118 - 5.892933087678905e-05 x**1 + 2.3178986039370123e-05 x**2 + 0.00028320046503272636 x**3 - 7.413659868838611e-05 x**4 - 0.0007190043777406841 x**5 -
0.005478338718269069 x**6 + 0.0009052362092180649 x**7 + 0.008047614732994075 x**8 - 0.00040853198223002313 x**9 - 0.003261609071280533 x**10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the resulting object as if it were a function, `poly_fitting(x)`. More details available in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial).